# C#: sort dictionary in descending order

Tags: c#, dictionary

How do I sort a keyvalue pair with descending order of their values?

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in keyvalue.OrderBy(key => key.Value))
            {
            }
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy`.

```
foreach (var item in keyvalue.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value))
{

}
```